# Crystal Report For Dynamic Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, datatable

I do a dynamic pivot sql query to get results like ,
[image]

ANd for that my query is given below,

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(AssortmentSize) 
                    from tbl_Assortment_Qty WHERE Head_Id=325
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

    set @query='SELECT                                                                      Description,AssortmentType, '+@cols+',ISNULL (size_unit_price,0) UnitPrice from 
             (
                SELECT DISTINCT H.Description,AssortmentType,AssortmentSize,AssortmentQty,B.size_unit_price FROM dbo.tbl_Assortment_Qty Q
                INNER JOIN 
dbo.tbl_Fabric_Order_Head H
 ON H.Head_ID=Q.Head_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 dbo.Budget_Accessories_Qty B
 ON B.head_Id=Q.Head_Id
 AND B.accessories=Q.AssortmentType

 WHERE Q.head_id=325
 ) x
            pivot 
            (
                SUM(AssortmentQty)
                for AssortmentSize in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Now I want to print the result datatable directly into Crystal report. I want it as it is, with the header names intact. Now I completely get stuck at this. I cant define columns fixed in crystal report, as they are Dynamic. The Size c(L,M,S,XL) may be other one, and I am not a crystal report expert. The most simple answer I require is, How to Print a DATATABLE directly into Crystal report, without defining its column fields??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to directly print a DataTable into a report without first specifying some kind of placeholders for your values. As a solution, you can use the technique used in this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20670/Dynamic-Crystal-Report-with-C.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll look into your example. Anyway, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

After mammoth search I finally come to the decision that what I want is impossible using crystal report, at my side. So I rather use crosstab by simplifying the query, i.e without using PIVOT. Now my result set looks like,
[image]